# Show that a differential is null at a maximum

Tags: analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I know it is a silly question, but I have a hard time proving that the differential at a critical point (say a maximum) is null.

I try to prove it using Taylor expansion around the optimum, but I can't figure out how to rearrange this expression:

$$ f(M+h)=f(M)+d_{M}f(h) + o(\lvert\lvert h \rvert\rvert)$$

Answer (score 1):

If $f\colon [a,b]\to\Bbb R$ has a local maximum at $c\in(a,b)$ (i.e., for all $h$ with $|h|$sufficiently small, we have $f(c+h)\le f(c)$) and $f'(x)$ exists, then $f'(c)=0$.

Indeed, if we had $f'(c)>0$, then for sufficiently small positive $h$, we'd have $\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}>\frac 12f'(c)>0$; and if $f'(c)<0$, then for sufficiently (absolutely) small negative $h$, $\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}<\frac 12f'(c)<0$. Both cases lead to $f(c+h)-f(c)>0$, contradiction.

Comment: Got it! But, my question is more how can I prove that the differential of a function is null at a critical point using the Taylor series expansion order 1.